# Not wanting to use if else but try except block in python

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to write a program that does the following in python:

accept three arguments: a prompt, a low acceptable limit, and a high acceptable limit;
if the user enters a string that is not an integer value, the function should emit the message Error: wrong input, and ask the user to input the value again;
if the user enters a number which falls outside the specified range, the function should emit the message Error: the value is not within permitted range (min..max) and ask the user to input the value again;
if the input value is valid, return it as a result.

I don't want to use if-else. I am learning catching exceptions in python. i want to use try-except

I have written the following code

```
def readint(prompt, min, max):
    try:
        theNum = int(input(prompt))
        if theNum in range(min, max+1):
            return theNum
    except ValueError: 
            return "Error: wrong input. The value is not within the permitted range (-10..10)"
            readint(prompt, min, max)
       
v = readint("Enter a number from -10 to 10: ", -10, 10)

print("The number is:", v)
```

The output prints out any number in the mentioned range but when a number not within the range is entered, the output says "The number is: None" and it does not re-prompt me to enter another number

Comment: You'll need to wrap the try/except block in a loop, e.g. `while True` if you want it to prompt until the user provides the correct input. If you do this, you can print the error message in the except block instead of returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` and `max` are keywords in python. I would avoid using them as variable names.

```
def readint(prompt, minimum, maximum):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
            assert minimum <= value <= maximum
            prompt = "Try again: "
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Not an integer")
        except AssertionError:
            print("Error: Value not within range")
        else:
            break
    return value

minimum = -10
maximum = 10

value = readint(f"Enter a number between {minimum} and {maximum}: ", minimum, maximum)
```

Comment: It works but the program works exactly like this with if-else. I didn't use any loop. I only placed the error statement and recall the function after the else.

Comment: You'll want to avoid calling the function recursively as a substitute for a loop. `sys.getrecursionlimit` returns the maximum recursion depth, which in Python 3.8.2 is set to `1000` by default. That means, even though it is unlikely to happen, if someone enters 1000 invalid integers in a row using your code, a `RecursionError` will be raised. Also, the call-stack won't look very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a typical retry loop that uses try/except:

```
def thing_to_retry():
    while True:
        try:
            return thing()
        except SomeError as e:
            print("Whoopsie! Error: {}".format(e))
```

Since the try/except is within the loop, any exception you catch will cause another loop iteration. Success will cause the function to return from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def readint(prompt, min, max):
    doIt = True
    while doIt:
    
        try:
            userInput = int(input(prompt))
            if userInput in range(min, max+1):
                doIt = False
                return userInput
            else:
                raise AssertionError
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: wrong input.")
        except AssertionError:
            print("The value is not within the permitted range (-10..10)") 
        except:
            doIt = True
        
v = readint("Enter a number from -10 to 10: ", -10, 10)

print("The number is:", v)
```

Comment: This could be a really good answer if you explained why the problem was happening, what you changed to fix it, and why it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_int(prompt, min, max):
    #
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
            assert min <= value <= max
            return value

        except AssertionError:
            print("Error: the value is not within permitted range (-10..10)")

        except ValueError:
            print("Error: wrong input")

        else:
            break

    #
v = read_int("Enter a number from -10 to 10: ", -10, 10)

print("The number is:", v)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem with None is that you do not write: return readint(prompt, min, max)
   You just write readint(prompt, min, max)
2. If you like recursion ( I don't) instead of a loop then you may try this:

> ```
> def readint(prompt, mini, maxi):    
>     try:
>         theNum = int(input(prompt))
>         assert theNum in range(mini, maxi + 1)
>         return theNum
>     except AssertionError:
>         print("Error: wrong input. The value is not within the permitted range (-10..10)")       
>     except ValueError:
>         print("This is not a number")
>     return readint(prompt, mini, maxi)
> ```